# Trying to grasp Go's pointers

Tags: pointers, go

I've written a small snippet to recursively walk a directory and return a slice of files (`[]string`) based on extension. It seems to work, but I cannot fully get the idea behind pointers and how to properly use it.

```
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

// aggregator slice should hold the result (a slice of filepaths)
// dir is the current directory being listed
// exts is a slice of extensions that should be included in the result
func recurse(aggregator *[]string, dir string, exts *[]string) []string {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    for _, file := range files {
        // current filepath
        path := filepath.Join(dir, file.Name())

        // if directory, recursively analyze it
        if file.IsDir() {
            *aggregator = recurse(aggregator, path, exts)

        // else check if file is of proper extension and add it to aggregator
        } else {
            for _, ext := range *exts {
                if (filepath.Ext(path) == ext) {
                    *aggregator = append(*aggregator, path)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return *aggregator
}

func getTemplates(templatesDir string, templatesExtensions ...string) {
    templates := recurse(&[]string{}, templatesDir, &templatesExtensions)

    // for testing purposes just print filepaths
    for _, t := range templates {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", t)
    }
}


func main() {
    getTemplates("./templates", ".tmpl", ".html")
}
```

The main question is using `*aggregator` (`aggregator *[]string`), `&[]string{}` and `*exts` (`exts *[]string`). I come from `javascript` world where every object is basically a pointer and you can only copy objects and arrays explicitly. Here, on the other hand, it seems that if I didn't use pointers (`*aggregator`, etc.), these objects would get copied on each function iteration.

Am I correct in this approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this visualization is not specifically about Go (it's about Java) yet it's a perfect one to actually visualize the usage of pointers and values (1):
[image]

As you see a pointer does not actually *contain* any data, but it *points to* the place where data resides. So any modifications that are made on that data via a pointer, are actually getting performed on the data itself. But the data do not necessarily reside where our pointer is being used.

There are different situations when we might need pointers. For example when you want to modify the actual values in one specific place (and not pass those values around) or when your data is too big that the cost would be just too high to send the actual content around. You can use a/some pointer to this big data and everybody (every function for example) that has a pointer to that data, can read it or modify it. And as just we said, we can have as many pointers to the same data as needed. So there may be many pointers to just the same, one data. The value of these pointers but is the same; which is the address of the source data (object).

(1) [Source](https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical/)

Comment: Got it, thanks. So for instance if I have a function which *does* return value (like in my example), pointers may be omitted, but if I have a function which *does not* return a value, but wants to modify the slice (add/remove items), I have to use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In go slices are reference types, along with maps and pointers (I'm pretty sure strings are too don't qoute me on it though :) see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ZRKSJ3GPkLw) for a discussion on this). So these particular types are automatically passed by reference. So the actual variable itself evaluates as a pointer where the value would be the reference address.
So in your case it would be safe and probably preferable to change `aggregator *[]string` to `aggregator []string` and your data will **not** be copied just a reference passed. Of course along with this change you will need to change all code that was previously dereferencing `aggregator` e.g.

```
// Change this line
*aggregator = append(*aggregator, path)
// To this
aggregator = append(aggregator, path)
```

The reasoning for doing this would likely stem from C based languages where arrays are simply pointer to the start of allocated memory.

**Note:** All other types including structs do not follow this pattern (interfaces are kind of another exception interesting [read](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)). Also this code looks like it could be greatly simplified with `filepath.Walk()`.

For a bit more information although more targeted at maps see [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) blog post.

Comment: Except that append() returns a value because it may change the underlying array, not just the slice, and that change would not be reflected in the caller if the slice isn't either passed by reference or returned by value (as append does).